# Глубокое копирование js

Tags: javascript, клонирование

Никак не могу понять где я допустил ошибку... 
Я написал функцию, которая должна делать копии объектов/массивов,вот она :

```
function copy(arr,deep){
  if(arr instanceof Object){
      var arr1 = {};
  }else if(arr instanceof Array){
      var arr1 = [];
  }else{
      return arr;
  }
  for(let key in arr){
      arr1[key] = copy(arr[key],true);
  }
  if(!deep){ 
      return arr1;
  }   
}
```

Она должна копировать массив с 30 объектами, объекты имеют глубину примерно уровня на три(они также имеют и методы).
После копирования этого массива, выходит одноуровневый массив с вложенными undefined. Где ошибка?

P. S. 
Незнаю нужно ли это кому, но вот рабочая версия:

```
function copy(arr){
if(arr.length){
    var arr1 = [];
}else if(typeof arr == "object"){
    var arr1 = {};
}else{
    return arr; 
}
for(let key in arr){
    if(typeof arr[key] == "function" || !arr[key].length || typeof arr[key] != "object")
        arr1[key] = arr[key];
    else 
        arr1[key] = copy(arr[key]);
}
return arr1;
}
```

Comment: А если `deep` - ничего не возвращать?

Comment: А какой тогда мне смысл от этой функции, если она ничего не будет возвращать?  Я собирался прогонять через нее объекты не один раз

Comment: Вы думаете, я от фонаря задал вопрос? Посмотрите на Ваш код. Если `deep == true`, что возвращает функция?

Comment: Простите, не совсем понял прошлый вопрос. Но теперь понял, т.е. когда  моя функция  доходила "до дна" она поднималась на один уровень и дальше ничего не возвращала кроме высшего уровня... Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции пропущено возвращение результата при `deep == true` и первом аргументе, являющимся массивом или объектом.

Еще. Посмотрите на пример кода - что он выводит в консоль.

```js
var a = [];
console.log(typeof a, a instanceof Array, a instanceof Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый незапарный способ глубокого копирования объектов:

```
const newObj = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(obj) );
```

))